# Javascript passing parameters into function

Tags: javascript

Hey, i cant seem to get this to work, im a little confused on how im supposed to pass the colour paramaters:

```
function colourGreen(red, green, blue)
        {
            document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(red,green,blue)';
        }
```

.............
.............

```
<input type="button" id = "button2" value="Price up" onclick = 'colourGreen(0,255,0)'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing this should do the trick

```
function colourGreen(red, green, blue)
        {
            document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+red+','+green+','+blue')';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...'rgb('+red+','+green+','+blue+')';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + red +', ' + green + ', ' + blue ')';
```